# Overwrite derived column in prefuse

Tags: java, prefuse

In a prefuse graph I have a derived column named `"distance"` created with [`Table.addColumn(String name, Expression expr)`](http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/data/Table.html#addColumn%28java.lang.String,%20prefuse.data.expression.Expression%29) and a boolean runtime variable called `normalize`. Now I want to change the expression used to calculate the column value during runtime, depending on the value of `normalize`, but there is no such thing as `replaceColumn()` or `deleteColumn()`. When I try to overwrite the old column by calling `addColumn()` again, I get a 'Table already has column with name "distance"'.

Can I somehow programatically change the expression used to calculate the column value of `distance` or make it dependend from the runtime variable `normalize`? I would rather not have two columns with different names, because the value is used from many places in the project and I would therefor have to implement a lot of case distinctions.

Answer (score 0):

prefuse has an `IfExpression` so you can make the derived column depend on `normalize`.

Alternatively there is a method `removeColumn(String)` in `Table`.

Comment: Ok, now I created an `IfExpression` passing an `AbstractPredicate` with `getBoolean()` overwritten to return `normalize`, but it seems that the derived column values are calculated when calling `addColumn(col, expr)` and not when calling the `Tuple.get...()` methods. So the returned values of the `IfExpression` chnage, when changing `normalize` but the values returned by `Tuple.get...()` don't.

Comment: Furthermore I tried `Table.removeColumn()` but here prefuse crashed passing a `TableEvent` to the cascaded visual table.